# How to get the "file_url" from serialize data in php?

Tags: php, wordpress, serialization

I am looking to get data `file_url` from this:

```
a:1:{s:5:"bIrq7";a:6:{s:14:"user_file_name";s:15:"Recruitment.pdf";s:9:"file_name";s:15:"recruitment.pdf";s:9:"file_path";s:76:"/home3/fashion/public_html/thesafetyjobs.com/wp-content/uploads/ninja-forms/";s:8:"file_url";s:71:"http://thesafetyjobs.com/wp-content/uploads/ninja-forms/recruitment.pdf";s:8:"complete";s:1:"1";s:9:"upload_id";s:2:"28";}}`
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What you have tried so far to get it ?

Comment: Have you tried maybe...`UNserialize`?

Comment: I try to get "s:5:"bIrq7" " & file_url from this data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `maybe_unserialize()` function this return an array
You can try this code

```
$data = 'a:1:{s:5:"bIrq7";a:6:{s:14:"user_file_name";s:15:"Recruitment.pdf";s:9:"file_name";s:15:"recruitment.pdf";s:9:"file_path";s:76:"/home3/fashion/public_html/thesafetyjobs.com/wp-content/uploads/ninja-forms/";s:8:"file_url";s:71:"http://thesafetyjobs.com/wp-content/uploads/ninja-forms/recruitment.pdf";s:8:"complete";s:1:"1";s:9:"upload_id";s:2:"28";}}';
$un_serialize = maybe_unserialize($data);
echo $un_serialize['bIrq7']['file_url'];
```

Comment: for this "bIrq7" data is dynamic. I always change.

Comment: Then store that dynamic variable in some variable like `$var='bIrq7'` and access file_url by `$un_serialize[$var]['file_url'];`